# Can't edit styles in Chrome Dev Tools while using Browser-sync

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

I use the latest Chrome version on Mac (83.0.4103.116), Gulp + Browser-sync.
In DevTools, after the Browser-sync applies the changes in `style.css` and reloads the page, I can't edit any style, it looks like default and blocked:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH1zQ.png)

It's very strange that when I'm reloading the page manually (`Cmd+R`), the styles are available for change again till the next Browser-sync reloading.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqSCb.png)

I've tried to reload the browser, to uninstall and install Browser-sync again, I didn't change the `gulpfile.js`.

So I can't even guess what's going wrong. What am I missing?

Gulpfile.js code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var bsync = require('browser-sync').create();


gulp.task('default', function() {
    bsync.init({
        server: ''
    });

gulp.watch('*.html')
    .on('change', bsync.reload);
gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss')
    .on('change', gulp.series('launch-sass'))    
});

gulp.task('launch-sass', function() {
return gulp.src('./sass/style.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
    .pipe(bsync.stream());
});
```

Comment: It's fixed in Chrome 85. You can test it already in Chrome Canary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Impossible to edit styles in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52582995/impossible-to-edit-styles-in-chrome)

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you for your answer, it have been working perfectly just couple of hours ago. I didn't update anything, including Chrome.

Comment: The reason is that there are two modes of CSS update in browser-sync. Until Chrome 85 only one mode was supported by devtools so when "it works" for you it means the classic mode was used. In Chrome 85 both modes will be supported.

Comment: @wOxxOm does that mean that browser-sync changed the CSS update mode from the classic to the second one without my knowledge, so it doesn't work well now? Unfortunately, I cannot go with Google Canary as I need to develop the page supported by stable browser versions only.